# Cannot create Jess plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jess

I have a Win 7 Professional machine.

I downloaded Eclipse, eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64. Worked successfully with some of its tutorials, but cannot get Jess in it as a plugin. Note:  Jess in the command (DOS) box works.

Also in my C:\Users\David\Downloads directory I have a) jess, an executable Jar File and b) Jess71p2, a WinZip File.

Under C:\Users\David\Eclipse I have following subdirectories: **eclipse**, **jess**, **Jess71p2**, META-INF, xmlsrc.

- List item

Under **eclipse** there are configuration, dropins, features, p2, plugins …. . dropins is empty, plugins has many (org.x, com.x but no gov.sandia.x)

- List item

Under **jess** there are directories awt, factory, jsr94, server swing, tools and xml and many class files.

- List item

Under **Jess71p2** there are directories bin, docs, eclipse, examples, lib.  Under its **eclipse** directory are gov.sandia.jess.debug_7.1.0, gov.sandia.jess.editor_7.1.0, gov.sandia.jess.feature_7.1.0, gov.sandia.jess.reteview_7.1.0, and gov.sandia.jess_7.1.0.  (They appear to be in the wrong directory?)

I tried to install the JessDE by using 7-Zip, Extract files.  I call up Eclipse, using C:\Users\David\workspace –clean.  Under Help – About Eclipse there are no Jess-related plugins.  No Jess editor.

Did I download the Eclipse runtime binary?  If so, I cannot find any distinction in the Eclipse site for choosing a “full Eclipse SDK,“ which I assume is source and not binary, and the Platform Runtime Binary.

Or did I extract incorrectly using 7-Zip?

Within Eclipse documentation I found a Platform Plug-in Developer guide, tried to use it to guide me thru pluging in Jess, but gave up as there was a choice to make that I couldn’t decide and, after trying unsuccessfully to do one, gave up.

I have tried several things but nothing works and the above description is of the current state of this mess.  Would greatly appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

I have your same problem. In mine Eclipse KEPLER version goes all right, but when I do the SAME installation in LUNA, something goes wrong.

Probably, the last version of JESS (7.1p2) doesn't is compatible with LUNA. I hope not.